# CakePHP & Swiftmailer not working after server migration - How to set it up again

Tags: cakephp, swiftmailer

I have migrated a CakePHP app from a server and set it up to a new server.

I have no experience using the specific framework, I have read online how to migrate it. Everything seems to be working fine except the mail functions.

The developer who has set it up used Swift Mailer component. Now there seems to be a connection error with the email.

I want to change the Swift Mailer connection values in order to perform some tests but can't find anywhere the file used to set up the Swift Mailer connection.

Is there any other way I can edit the connection values?

Comment: Please present some codes, especially that in charge of sending email. Also note that you will need to configure your new server to work with your smtp service.

Comment: Share here the config values for email (except passwords)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I managed to figure it out. The guy who had created the cakephp app had set up the email with the gmail STP. I had to disable the mail function from the server, add new mx values of the gmail and finally after that talk with the hosting company to whitelist the port it was used to connect with gmail servers ip. Not a cakephp issue after all. I am sorry for any inconvenience caused.